# Tags for "source generators" in C# need some cleanup

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

C# has a fairly new feature called "source generators". It appears there have already been two tags created for this topic, [sourcegenerators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sourcegenerators) and [csharp-source-generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/csharp-source-generator).  With a [single exception](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67985151/1467396), all questions tagged with the former ([sourcegenerators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sourcegenerators)) appear to be about C# source generators. As such, these appear to be synonyms.

At the time of this writing, the [csharp-source-generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/csharp-source-generator) tag only has 17 questions using it, as opposed to the 41 in use by [sourcegenerators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sourcegenerators).  To me this means the majority of users agree (as do I) that the "csharp" part is not necessary and we should just use [sourcegenerators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sourcegenerators) instead. *But* the tag was created as one smashed word, whereas the convention here seems to be to use dashes between words (should be source-generators).

Here is what I think should happen, but I defer to others who know more about Stack Overflow rules and conventions than I do:

1. [csharp-source-generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/csharp-source-generator) is redundant and there are only a small number of posts with that tag. I think it should be "burninated". Perhaps adding a synonym is better?
2. [sourcegenerators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sourcegenerators) should be renamed to [source-generators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/source-generators). Not sure how this is to be done.
3. In order to prevent any confusion about code generation in general, [source-generators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/source-generators) should have in the wiki excerpt that it is for C# source generators specifically, and if the user wants to talk about other code generation, they should use the [code-generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-generation) tag instead (I've already added this, but it is pending peer review).

I'm happy to help do any legwork that needs to be done to fix this (assuming I have those privileges), but I would like a moderator (or at least someone with more reputation points than me) to either agree with my assessments or give other direction on how it should really be handled.

Comment: I'd vote to synonym [[tag:csharp-source-generaor]] to the other tag, and also rename [[tag:sourcegenerators]] to "source-generators" (that's something mods can do I think). I would like to voice concern though about "source-generators" sounding quite generic,  and also sounding really really close to [[tag:code-generation]].

Comment: Maybe another alternate name would be better? [[tag:c#-source-generators]]? [[tag:c#-source-generation]]? Maybe just [[tag:source-generators]] with [[tag:c#]]? I don't know if any of these are better than what you've already shared though.

Comment: Having [[tag:c#-source-generator]] be the primary tag sounds like a better way to go, if the tag is to be for a language-specific formulation within C#, rather than a concept which is basically a synonym of [[tag:code-generation]]. I, too, think that it would be fairly easy for users to confuse [[tag:sourcegenerators]] or [[tag:source-generators]] with [[tag:code-generation]].

Comment: I agree with [tag:C#-source-generator] being the primary tag.  [tag:source-generators] is too generic, and by the OP's own admission, the tag only applies to the C# programming language.

Comment: @Makyen it's true, that source-generators in question are very specific to C# toolset, similarly to i.e. T4 templates. If we focus on that specific-ness, I think we should make it more specific than just C#, because there are more source-generators for C# than just this one we talk about now. This one was added in .Net SDK 5.0, Roslyn 3.8 compiler version, or C# 9, if I didn't mess up the numbers. Those all are tightly coupled. Personally, I'd vote for [C#9-source-generators] or [source-generators-C#9]. Short 'C#' just doesn't feel right.

Comment: To be honest, I coined a term "genalyzers" to call those source generators, as they seem to be built upon source-analyzer feature that was added to the toolset few versions ago, or at least it looks like that. They are even shown in VisualStudio in the same place along with analyzers, so "genalyzers" feel just right for that, and is totally unambiguous, at least unless you think about DNA analyzers heh :)

Answer (score 24):

I concur with Makyen:

- Rename [csharp-source-generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/csharp-source-generator) to [c#-source-generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23-source-generator)
- Retag all questions using [sourcegenerators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sourcegenerators) to use [c#-source-generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23-source-generator)
- Once [sourcegenerators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sourcegenerators) has no questions due to the above retagging, it will be automatically removed by the system

The quantity of questions is small enough that going the "long way around" isn't too much extra effort, and it's definitely worth it to have a tag that is properly descriptive.

Should this consensus be adopted, I'm happy to assist with retagging.

Comment: Please don't manually retag these questions. It's easy for a moderator to accomplish this tag renaming without having to edit the posts, given that it's *just* renaming the tag and not differentiating between questions which should or should not have the source or destination tag. Manual processing is for when it's complex, this one isn't.

Comment: @Makyen Did you miss point #2 above? Unless you have a tool to merge tags (as opposed to just renaming), I don't see how you could accomplish this.

Comment: Moderators can merge tags.

Comment: I just came to meta to raise a question about this very issue... Are there any plans to do this? It's been nearly 2 years since this answer